# Using map() in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable. It contains telephone numbers.

I am using like this:

```
println(person.phoneNumbers!.map( {$0.value} ))
```

Output:

```
[555-478-7672, (408) 555-5270, (408) 555-3514]
```

You can see there are three phone numbers. How can I iterate this variable?

I need something like this:

```
Phone 1: 555-478-7672
Phone 2: (408) 555-5270
Phone 3: (408) 555-3514
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is for Swift 1.2

```
for (index, number) in enumerate(person.phoneNumbers!.map { $0.value }) {
    println("Phone \(index): \(number)")
}
```

And since I am scared by this `!` I would go with the following version

```
if let numbers = person.phoneNumbers {
    for (index, number) in enumerate(numbers.map { $0.value }) {
        println("Phone \(index): \(number)")
    }
}
```

### Update

The following code tries to answer the question added in the comments below.

```
if let numbers = person.phoneNumbers {
    let list = numbers.map { $0.value }
    let json : [String:AnyObject] = ["phoneNumbers": list]
}
```

### Update #2

Please find below the second block of code, updated for Swift 2.0

```
if let numbers = person.phoneNumbers {
    for (index, number) in (numbers.map { $0.value }).enumerate() {
        print("Phone \(index): \(number)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is irrelevant but could you replace the println line with creating a json with this numbers?

Comment: With `JSON` you mean a `Dictionary` like this `[String:AnyObject]`? Or you are using a specific library like `SwiftyJSON`?

Comment: The problem is that `JSON` is a **format not a type**. If you tell me the `type` of the output I can help you.

Comment: I need a json output like this: ["number 1","number 2","number 3" ...]

Comment: Ok, so you want this type: `[String]`? (It's an array of `String`)

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: No I need to append each number to a json variable.

Comment: Hmm... can you declare a variable that will contain the result? I will populate that variable for you.

Comment: As I said I have to create a json like this: http://pastebin.com/KtugN2FC So  when I iterating all numbers also i have to add to json each number.

Comment: Yes, this is awesome. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, I just updated the second block of code to Swift 2.0. I updated the second block instead of the first one because this is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
for number in person.phoneNumbers!.map( {$0.value} ) {
    println(number)
}
```

Comment: What do you suggest for preventing from nil values? I mean if user phone is nil then what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this,

```
let extracted  = person.phoneNumbers.enumerate().map { index, phone in
  return "Phone \(index):\(phone.value)"
}
```